# python list values of list in a sql statement without a for loop

Tags: python, mysql, loops, teradata

This is my data:

```
mylist=["happy" , "sad", "cute"]
country = 'US'
```

mytable

```
id terms values
1   happy  3
2   sad    4
3   angry  5
```

in python my sql query looks like this:

```
    myquery= 
"""select * from mytable where country = '%s' and terms is in ('%s', '%s');""" %(country, tuple(mylist))
```

error not enough arguments for format string.

Comment: It would be dangerous to create your queries like that (You are opening yourself upto SQL injection) , use your sql driver's `.execute()` and pass in the joined `myList` as argument to it.

Answer (score 0):

python's db adapter has provided the parameter formatting, you only need to use it:

```
cursor.execute('select * from mytable where terms in %s and country = %s;', (tuple(mylist), country))
```

See more: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14

Comment: @ piglei I made a small edit to query , could you help?

Comment: @jxn, edited, it's easy to add arguments when using `execute(statement, arguments)`.